# Clear Tasks in Google earth engine

Tags: javascript

I am new to using the Google earth engine.
In the google earth engine, I need to clear the failed tasks that are red. I clicked on the X but I cannot remove the Tasks.
Is there JavaScript codes to clear the Tasks.
This is the picture of it.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRZFc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cancel all tasks pending in the queue. Use `earthengine task cancel all`.

A discussion can be found here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324502/clear-task-list-in-the-earth-engine-command-line-tool/364812